# Factory pattern with a class that can has different class sub types

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have data from multiple organisations (police, fire, office) that need output in different formats.

To achieve this, I defined the following (this is a little simplified):

Transaction class -

1. "Success" indicator - Boolean.
2. "Type of department"- String or Enum.
3. A class which can be of any type - Police, Fire or Office (My question is on this as you will see).
4. A GenerateOutput() method - to handle generation of file formats.

Police class

1. Age - String
2. VehicleNumber - Integer
3. Supervisor - String

Fire class

1. Name - String
2. FireEngineNumber  - Integer
3. County - Enum
4. WorkTimings - Enum

Office Class

1. Age - String
2. DeskNumber - Integer
3. Department - String
4. PayScale - Enum
5. IsManagement - Bool

As you can see, the Police, Fire and Office classes dont share anything in common and are primarily intended as data carrying entities. I intend to use a Factory to return an appropriate generic (not a C# generic) Transaction object with the data (Transaction object with *Police, Fire or Office* data within it) and then pass the returned object to a Strategy pattern which determines the file format (CSV, Excel, or XML; specified in a configuration file) each one needs.

My problem is in the definition of the Transaction object.

1. What type does the class in "3." of the Transaction class need to be? The data for each org differs, there are no common members, I am unable to define a common class for all.
2. Is the overall design appropriate? What other designs should I consider?

Based on Peter's comments below:
I think using generics might work, I ran into a problem though. I would like to use a factory to return the object requested, using GetTransactionObject, as below. What should be the return type of GetTransactionObject to accomodate this.

class TransactionFactory
{

```
        Dictionary<string, Type> typeClassLookup;

    public TransactionFactory()
    {
        typeClassLookup = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        typeClassLookup.Add("Police", typeof(PoliceData));
        typeClassLookup.Add("Fire", typeof(FireData));
    }

    Transaction<????> GetTransactionObject(string org)
    {

        if( typeClassLookup.TryGetValue(org, out typeValue))
        {
            switch (typeValue.ToString())
            {
                case "policeData":
                    transactionObject = new Transaction<PoliceData>() { Data = new PoliceData(), params = null};
                case "FireData":
                    transactionObject = new Transaction<FireData>() {Data = new FireData(), params = null};
            }
        }
        return transactionObject;
```

Comment: #2 is certainly opinion based. For #1 you can still have a common base class even if they have no fields in common. It'll just be an empty (probably abstract) base class with no members (or it might contain some common abstract functions that the derived classes must implement). Or you could use an interface as a marker. Without more information, it's really too broad.

Comment: I believe you can have a common interface may be called `IWorkPlace` which could be an office or a police station, or a fire department which defines some common behaviors. The flaw would be that if the types have other behaviors defined which are not common, then you might have to cast that object every now and then to use the specific behaviors, but still it might solve the purpose.

Comment: Thanks Matt, would appreciate if you took a look at the question now, more detail has been added.

Comment: Thats right Nikhil, I would like keep casting those objects into appropriate types as a last resort. Would you have another design in mind with the additional info?

Comment: You should post the actual code.

Comment: Think about the behaviour that the Transaction has to implement.  Is there a common thing that they all need to do, regardless of the properities they posess?  If so then this should be the basis for your base class or interface.  The Transaction class would use an object of this type (base or interface) and use the common behaviour (method) which would be implemented by each of the derived classes.

Comment: either a generic wrapper or a common interface like IDepartment  
or a combination of the 2

Transaction<T> where T : IDepartment

Comment: BTW its NILESH!! What is it that you intend to do in strategy? Just print them in a specific format? If its just exporting data in that case you can use a common interface to get the required object and then use reflection to dump the data to xml, xl etc.

Comment: Oops Nilesh, auto correct messed that up. The strategy pattern is to create a CSV, an XML or another format with the data in the class (Police, Fire or Office). The Transaction object would have detail on the format required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the types *really* have nothing in common, then you need no explicit base class. `System.Object` suffices, just as with many other generic types (i.e. any generic type lacking a constraint).

In other words, you could declare as:

```
class Transaction<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
    public T Entity { get; private set; }

    public Transaction(bool success, T entity)
    {
        Success = success;
        Entity = entity;
    }

    public void GenerateOutput() { /* something goes here */ }
}
```

Personally, I would avoid adding a "department type" member. After all, that's implicit from the type parameter `T`. But you could add that easily to the above if you want.

If and when you find that the types do have something in common, such that your `Transaction<T>` type needs to do more than simply hold onto an instance of one of those types (which is about all it can do without a constraint), then you will be able to put that commonality into an interface or base class (depending on the specific need), and specify that in a constraint for the `Transaction<T>` class.

Note that it's not clear what you mean for the `GenerateOutput()` to do, or how it should work. But assuming that you want output that is specific for each `Entity` value, it seems to me that *that* is your "something in common". I.e., it's not the `Transaction<T>` class at all that needs to implement that method, but rather each entity type. In that case, you have something like this:

```
interface IDepartmentEntity
{
    void GenerateOutput();
}

class Office : IDepartmentEntity
{
    public void GenerateOutput() { /* department-specific logic here */ }
}

// etc.
```

Then you can declare:

```
class Transaction<T> where T : IDepartmentEntity
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
    public T Entity { get; private set; }

    public Transaction(bool success, T entity)
    {
        Success = success;
        Entity = entity;
    }

    public void GenerateOutput() { Entity.GenerateOutput(); }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Per Prasant's follow-up edit, with a request for advice on the `GetTransactionObject()`…

The right way to do this depends on the caller and the context, a detail not provided in the question. IMHO, the *best* scenario is where the caller is aware of the type. This allows the full power of generics to be used.

For example:

```
class TransactionFactory
{
    public Transaction<T> GetTransactionObject<T>()
        where T : IDepartmentEntity, new()
    {
        return new Transaction<T>()
        {
            Data = new T(),
            params = null
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call like this:

```
Transaction<FireData> transaction = factory.GetTransactionObject<FireData>();
```

The caller, of course already knowing the type it is creating, then can fill in the appropriate properties of the `transaction.Data` object.

If that approach is not possible, then you will need for `Transaction<T>` itself to have a base class, or implement an interface. Note that in my original example, the `IDepartmentEntity` interface has only one method, and it's the same as the `GenerateOutput()` method in the `Transaction` class.

So maybe, that interface is really about generating output instead of being a data entity. Call it, instead of `IDepartmentEntity`, something like `IOutputGenerator`.

In that case, you might have something like this:

```
class Transaction<T> : IOutputGenerator
{
    // all as before
}

class TransactionFactory
{
    public IOutputGenerator GetTransactionObject(string org)
    {
        if( typeClassLookup.TryGetValue(org, out typeValue))
        {
            switch (typeValue.ToString())
            {
                case "policeData":
                    transactionObject = new Transaction<PoliceData>() { Data = new PoliceData(), params = null};
                case "FireData":
                    transactionObject = new Transaction<FireData>() {Data = new FireData(), params = null};
            }
        }
        return transactionObject;
    }
}
```

This is an inferior solution, as it means the caller can only directly access the `IOutputGenerator` functionality. Anything else requires doing some type-checking and special-case code, something that really ought to be avoided whenever possible.

Note: if the `Transaction` type has other members which, like the `GenerateOutput()` method, are independent of the contained type `T` here, and which would be useful to callers who don't know `T`, then a possible variation of the above is to not reuse the interface used for the department-specific data types, but instead declare a base class for `Transaction<T>`, named of course `Transaction`, containing all those members not related to `T`. Then the return value can be `Transaction`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might work. If you can look at the edited question for a question on the factory method, it would be great.

Comment: I actually prefer the inferior solution. Just because I think the caller of the factory need not know the type to be returned. Isn't that the point of a factory where the caller passes arguments and gets the appropriate object? I might be wrong and would like to know what you think.

Comment: @Prasant: different factories have different goals and work in different ways. I would not agree that _the point_ of a factory is not to know the type of the object being returned. For me, the more salient question is: does the caller actually know the type. If the caller cannot or should not know the type for some reason, then having the factory method do that work makes sense. But if the caller always knows what type of object to expect to be returned, it makes more sense to let the caller provide that type to the factory method. I don't know enough about your caller to know what's best here

Comment: @Prasant: as an example of a factory method where the type is known by the caller, consider the various `Tuple.Create()` overloads. Clearly that's a valid and useful factory pattern implementation, and yet the caller just as clearly dictates the type of the object returned. Note also that at least Wikipedia distinguishes between `factory method pattern` and the more general `factory pattern`. In their view, the `factory method pattern` is what you're describing: the caller specifically doesn't know the type returned. But that's not required for factories in general.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What type does the class in "3." of the Transaction class need to be?

To decouple your department classes from the various export types, I recommend you make the department classes implement a common interface. Something like this:

```
public interface Exportable {
    // return a list of attribute names, values, and types to export
    IList<Tuple<String, String, Type>> GetAttributes();
}
```

For example:

```
public class Police : Exportable {
    public IList<Tuple<String, String, Type>> GetAttributes() {
        // return list size 3 - attribute info for Age, VehicleNumber, Supervisor
    }
}
```

> 2. Is the overall design appropriate? What other designs should I consider?

The `Transaction` class design doesn't seem well suited for this problem.

Consider an `Export` class with a method for each export type, each method which receives the attributes returned from the `Exportable` interface method. Basic outline:

```
public static class Export {
    public static boolean CSV(IList<Tuple<String, String, Type>> attributes) {
        // export attributes to CSV, return whether succeeded
    }

    public static boolean Excel(IList<Tuple<String, String, Type>> attributes) {
        // export attributes to Excel, return whether succeeded
    }

    // same thing for XML
}
```